# Tomcat 7 shows almost every day service temporalily unavailable at the same time

Tags: java, tomcat, server

Good morning friends. In recent times, almost every day the server is showing the error service temporarily unavailable message and I just restart tomcat and the applications normalize. Apparently, this problem always presents itself at the same time, three o'clock in the morning. Early in the morning I looked at the tomcat log on the server and these errors appeared in the log. I would be very grateful if anyone knows what it could be. Because it wasn't me who set up this server and I'm a little lost.

```
GRAVE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5a346e8f]) and a value of type [java.lang.Class] (value [class oracle.sql.AnyDataFactory]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22/07/2022 03:00:07 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
GRAVE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@28469c8d]) and a value of type [java.lang.Class] (value [class oracle.sql.TypeDescriptorFactory]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22/07/2022 03:00:07 com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter destroy
INFO: PrettyFilter shutting down...
22/07/2022 03:00:08 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
GRAVE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.context.ApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance(ApplicationContext.java:43)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.java:30)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2168)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2144)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:295)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:282)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5829)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1576)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
22/07/2022 03:00:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
22/07/2022 03:00:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
GRAVE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:715)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    ... 17 more
22/07/2022 03:00:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
GRAVE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:715)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    ... 17 more
22/07/2022 03:00:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
22/07/2022 03:00:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
GRAVE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:475)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:715)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
22/07/2022 03:00:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
GRAVE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:475)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:715)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more
22/07/2022 03:00:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
22/07/2022 03:00:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
GRAVE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8009
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:715)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:452)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    ... 16 more
22/07/2022 03:00:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
GRAVE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8009
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:715)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:452)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Is it always in the 03:00 minute? And, 3 AM in what time zone? (Tip: Log in UTC, with an indicator of offset)

Comment: Seems that the `com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter` class is triggering some process which eventually causes that the server gets incompletely shut down (surely because some daemon threads could not be stopped), so that the ports are not properly released and the server cannot be restarted because the ports are still used. Have you seeked the webapp which contains the PrettyFilter class?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a process that is trying to bounce Tomcat in the middle of the night. Evidence:

1. You have a message in the log saying `The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5a346e8f]) and a value of type [java.lang.Class] (value [class oracle.sql.AnyDataFactory]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.` This message is shown during application shut-down, and application shut-downs are typically performed when the server is being shut-down.
2. You have a message in the log saying `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`. This message is shown during container startup.

If your Tomcat restart process does not wait for Tomcat to completely shut-down before trying to start another instance, you may end up in a state where the new process fails to bind to the port (and therefore will not be listening for requests) and then the old process shuts-down, freeing-up the port. You now have a service that isn't reachable.

I would recommend a few things:

1. Reconsider nightly restarts. Why are you doing them? If you have bugs, fix them instead of restarting the service all the time to mitigate those bugs.
2. Check your restart process to ensure that the old process stops completely before starting the new process.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, so I didn't configure this tomcat and it seems to me that at this time of 03:00 every time it restarts, sometimes it gives an error in this process and sometimes it doesn't. I believe it's not a bug in the application but an error in the server configuration, because the application only gives an error at the same time apparently. I just restart the server, when it is not responding, after this process it is making the service unavailable. Can you tell me if there is any tomcat configuration that can be causing it to always restart at the same time?